# Any advice for my grass problem?

Tags: grass, seeds, lawn-repair, grubs, wasps

I’ve got a little issue in my backyard with growing some grass.
For starters, the yard is in a very sun exposed spot. I’m located in CT, USA.

Last year I believe I had grubs in the yard which ate away the roots of the grass and I was left with a big patch of dead grass which came up very easily in sheets when raked. I threw down about 3/4 of a big bag of grass seed about a month ago and now I’m left with what I have in the pictures below.

I watered it every day but only a few patches of grass actually grew. I now have some wasps who burrowed in the dirt patch.

My question for someone who may know better is what do I do now?
I have a bag of grub pesticide I was going to spray down but can I throw some more seed down? Is it too late? Anything I can do about the wasps as well as the grub pesticides?

Thank you[image]

Comment: It certainly sounds like curl grubs - the grass coming up in sheets. I recommend a live nematode application, which worked for me the two times I used it.